# Changing displayed hostname in bash prompt based on login credentials

Tags: ssh, bash, hostname

I host several domains on one server.

I would like to be able to change the displayed hostname in my bash prompt to indicate which one I picked when ssh'ing into the server.

My prompt is as follows:

```
\u@\h
```

This displays as:

```
user@hostname
```

How would I change the `\h` to show which domain I had logged-into (blah.net, hmm.com, etc)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that `ssh` finds lines in `ssh_config(5)` by string matching, so it's OK if all the IP's are the same.

What you want, then, are

- Different lines in `.ssh/config` for each system, use `HostName` to give `ssh` the real host domain name
- Have three different environment variables with different prompts in them in your local environment
- Have each line in `.ssh/config` send a different variable using `SendEnv`, see `man ssh_config`.
- Make your prompt out of all three (two will always be null)
- Put `AcceptEnv *` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and `sudo kill -1 $(cat /var/run/sshd.pid)`
  (`AcceptEnv E1 E2 E3` should also work.)

#### Example.

Client `.ssh/config`

```
Host barb
        HostName deb
        SendEnv BARB

Host jane
        HostName deb
        SendEnv JANE

Host deb barb jane
        Protocol 2
        ForwardAgent yes
        Compression no
```

Server `.bashrc`

```
PS1='$BARB$JANE.otherstuff...'
```

Server `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
...
AcceptEnv *
```

Comment: I would be nervous about `AcceptEnv *` being a security issue. In any case "don't open what you don't need" applies.

Comment: Dammit I knew there must have been something like SendEnv...one must remember to read manpage before posting :) Great answer.

Answer (score 4):

Do your domains all have different IPs?

If so, you can use the variable $SSH_CONNECTION once you are logged in.

If not, then it is impossible to differentiate, all the server sees is the IP address, there is no such thing as name-based ssh.

Comment: no - all the same IP.. they're fairly low-traffic domains on this server

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this could be to make entries for each of your hostnames in your local ~/.ssh/config, configured to connect to different **ports** on your server.

`Host foo
  HostName www.foo.com
  Port 1022`

Host bar
  HostName www.bar.com
  Port 2022

Then your ~/.bashrc on the server can parse the SSH_CONNECTION environment variable and pick out the port you've connected to, and change the prompt accordingly.

`case $(ruby -e 'puts ENV["SSH_CONNECTION"].split[-1]') in
  1022)
    WEBHOST="www.foo.com"
  ;;
  2022)
    WEBHOST="www.bar.com"
  ;;
  *)
    WEBHOST="www.foobar.com"
  ;;
esac`

PS1="\n\u@$WEBHOST \w\n$?> "

Obviously you would need ruby in your path for this, but you see what I mean.

Comment: Or you could do the same thing without `ruby` using bash: `sshconn=($SSH_CONNECTION); case "${sshconn[3]}" in`

Comment: nice, cheers :)

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to use the `SendEnv` directive (protocol 2 is required and sshd on the remote machine must be configured for AcceptEnv to include the name of the variable you want to use):

On the local machine:

```
export dest=example.com; ssh -o "SendEnv dest" username@$dest
```

On the remote machine, in ~/.bashrc:

```
PS1="...${dest}..."
```

Where the ellipses represent the rest of the stuff in your prompt.

If you edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to add a variable you may have to send SIGHUP to `sshd`.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you already use bash on these domains, edit the .bashrc file to add the line:

PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '

So that when you login and switch to bash the username and hostname are displayed.

Comment: thanks for that .. but my prompt already does this. the "`h`" tells the prompt to use the results of `hostname` in the display. `hostname` does not change based on which incoming domain name you used, but uses the canonical name of the device

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is **to specify** prompt (PS1) with correct hostname during connection to a server.
Assuming you use ssh client on Linux machine you can do it by running command:

```
ssh -t username@hostname-001 "export PS1='\u@hostname-001'; bash --login"
```

I found this technique very useful while managing connections to many servers without proper hostname set (like in EC2 amazon default hostnames). 
I wrote a small bash helper function, used bash aliases and put it in .bashrc file.

```
function __ssh_helper {
    local user=$1
    local host=$2
    local txtgrn='\e[0;32m'
    local txtblu='\e[0;34m'
    local txtcyn='\e[0;36m'
    local txtrst='\e[0m'
    ssh -t ${user}@${host} "export PS1='[${txtcyn}\u${txtrst}@${txtgrn}${host}${txtrst} \W]\$ '; bash --login"
}

alias hostname-001.prod='__ssh_helper username hostname-001.prod'
alias hostname-002.prod='__ssh_helper username hostname-002.prod'
```

I used /etc/hosts file to point hostname-00(1|2).prod to ip addresses. To add new ssh connection simply: 1. add hostname to /etc/hosts file; 2. add an alias to .bashrc; 3. pick up changes by sourcing .bashrc file. Hope it helps someone :-)